# Invalid eventListener for forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to catch the `invalid` event for forms, but it doesn't seem to happen?

https://codepen.io/MartinMuzatko/pen/VzWwxG?editors=1010

For my use case, I need to have the listener on the form (for asynchronous form validation). So attaching the listener to individual inputs is not an option for me.

According to the spec, forms should fire an `invalid` event when some of the input is invalid.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#client-side-form-validation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 'invalid' event is not "bubbled" . It fires on the specific input element which is invalid and won't bubble up to the form element. You need to attach the listener on the input element.

```
var input = document.querySelector('form input')

input.addEventListener('invalid', (e)=>{
    console.log('invalid')
});
```

Updated pen:
https://codepen.io/theLufenk/pen/WEONBw?editors=1010

Or if you want to catch the event at form level, you will have to use event capturing.

```
var form = document.querySelector('form')

form.addEventListener('invalid', (e)=>{
    console.log('invalid')
},true)
```

Update Pen: https://codepen.io/theLufenk/pen/Ojgmxz?editors=1011

Comment: So what does that part of the spec mean, when they say "When a form is submitted, invalid events are fired at each form control that is invalid, and then at the form element itself"
When is the `invalid` event ever going to be fired in the form itself?

Comment: It is not a bubbled event. However, you can use "capturing" to listen to it. See my updated answer.

Comment: Sadly there is no invalid event on the form itself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#Events. So in relation to onsubmit, there is no single oninvalid event on the form, but several events for every invalid input element in the form. A solution could be to use debounce to get just one event.